# Is there an official source of info and decision-making about the ERC20 Token Standard?

Tags: erc-20

I have been trying to trace information about the ERC20 Token Standard to an official source, and everything seems to go back to the (now closed) github thread where the standard was discussed and developed. There is also now an Ethereum Wiki page that describes the key functions and events that need to be included in a smart token contract to meet the ERC20 standard. Both links are at the end of this message.

Are these two pages official public statements and descriptions of ERC20?

Part of why I am asking is that I wonder whether the ERC20 token standard is still being refined. The github thread is now closed, so it's unclear where people can go to offer feedback about ERC20 or participate in its evolution. So, part of my question is: who currently gets to make decisions about the ERC20 Token Standard and how it unfolds from here?

Github link: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
Ethereum Wiki: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard